# Modifying return value of a property in a MVC Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC .NET Model and one of the properties in the model is set to return System.DateTime.

```
public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

In my UI I am binding this property to a Kendo Grid and formatting that to display the date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format. Kindo UI has built in filters. That filter does not work as intended on the date because the filter component is matching with the value that came in from the model instead of matching it with the displayed value(which is formatted). We cannot convert the property that is bound to the Kindo grid on the fly.

Is there any way that we can modify the return value of the model's property?
I tried doing this:

```
public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get { return Convert.ToDateTime(CreatedDate.ToShortDateString()); } set { CreatedDate = value; } }
```

But this throws a StackOverFlowException. Is there a way to return a modified value from the model?

Comment: You need to store the value in a field.

Comment: The property is in a model. It is bound to a database column. If I store it in a different field, would it still grab the database value?

Comment: EF uses the property; it doesn't know or care how the property is implemented.